# Setting the applcation to use "y-down" in LibGDX

Tags: java, math, libgdx, axis

http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2447
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html

There's hundreds of other links I could show you that I've looked at, but it's just not worth it because they all say the same thing.

```
public class InGame implements Screen {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    GameWorld world;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        world = new GameWorld();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
            world.render(batch, delta);
        batch.end();

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? WHY is my world still being rendered with the 0,0 being at the bottom right. The math behind this while trying to work on my Tile-System is driving me absolutely insane.

**World->Render**

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch, float delta) {
    for(int xAxis = 0; xAxis < worldColumns; xAxis++) {
        for(int yAxis = 0; yAxis < worldRows; yAxis++) {
            tiles[xAxis][yAxis].render(batch, delta);
        }
    }
}
```

**WorldTile->Render**

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch, float delta) {
        myShape.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        myShape.setColor(tileColor);
        myShape.rect(pos.getX(), pos.getY(), TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
        myShape.end();
    }
```

The "pos" is the Position(x, y) that was passed in the World class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing a Sprite or TextureRegion using your SpriteBatch the code should work fine. However, you pass your SpriteBatch 'batch' all the way down to `WorldTile.render` and never use it?! Instead you use `myShape` which I assume is a ShapeRenderer. You need to set the projection matrix for the ShapeRenderer as well otherwise it will draw 'upside-down'.
Try calling `myShape.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);` before you use your myShape.

Its probably best to declare and initialise myShape in your InGame class, use`myShape.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);`, and then pass myShape down to tiles.render() as you did with your SpriteBatch.

Hope this helps.